# log in with python using cookies and requests

Tags: python, cookies, python-requests

I need to log in to a site using python and requests. Here are the steps:

1- Open the login page in chrome. The website sets multiple cookies in my browser

2- When the log in form is submitted, some cookies are also included in the request header.

EDIT:
The original post contained a lot of data that wasn't compulsory for http headers .With help from one of the users, I was able to strip a lot of garbage off the requests. The following request is accepted by the webserver (I tested it using hurl.it):

```
Accept: */*
Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Length: 85
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
Cookie: www_amsterdam-dance-event_nl_session=JQBfAsd9iLZ7O7WbBr1JqdMTBt%2BzVE1fNkpLszZRu1G%2BDmSR81le4m0TAMm8S%2B%2FgJZBcHIlUwnvknXiSI2Za1s2Pct2gRNFuOlEaIwJx3OilOEUqNAlwCjecdeih3OieoZ2K%2FOyaqkNwWa86kiXhJTi9%2FvKIp4H9aaYTfuT1OTrCmNf2tTA0RDN2oW8WKZnCiIs40CuzaVg0pXpqE%2BMmigRqPJS%2FNgjrIuik8K5WMeOe7LNNQ3QIJZtsIeKEVsWfGum4pbT7C0c1wEYxJzIGG%2FqtxSSuBXArO0LvZPz6ResHNQZkdd9aExIyc4nN66rG%2BFKh4SMGLBei%2FPqjIEJeLtrjzuK9gpKYbTgKOCvlhH85vA7J52m4RTqazJOdgYLmcUKJzHA1Z8o29k16WGGWfqDD6aAPXdUbvKpoKhOoOTY%3D5322e6246ce84554a185eb4d73ad2e79ced12d87;
Host: www.amsterdam-dance-event.nl
User-Agent: runscope/0.1
```

However, I still can't get it running through requests. By enabling debugging mode, I found the exact request sent by requests module

```
send: 'POST /my-ade/login/ HTTP/1.1\r\nHost: www.amsterdam-dance-event.nl\r\nContent-Length: 85\r\nAccept-Encoding: gzip,deflate\r\nAccept: */*\r\nUser-Agent:  runscope/0.1\r\nConnection: keep-alive\r\nCookie: www_amsterdam-dance-event_nl_session=D21j0ZV%2FIxV48CQvUITnehC%2Bbd0tNeJBaU3DXSipK2t%2F4XpsZcAqr3TkANLaFvjijTONRtg8kpC%2BycfOh5l4SuKeLzGUfGH96QHywMwf9hue2sj44e%2ByWIlDUp06dV4Ztm63b5Kp%2Fzyl3HudWNihhaKt6NxEsSauQjOXUiU2WdGFxTafgR9y36mcNyEXu3zcSr9Dw9Y08i%2FlFoIy8Zxny5xjhOJ7pgsKguxKvHqZHRcmAcgcjNJwSBN%2F5KYeHH3Hhz5i2wvR7MR8UIx9fHWcEh9HHYsAO8VdKS6v3b1yfF2%2F2ECdE1MYRATDw5yxbUT%2Bo4949PJkmMM%2FTikABhw06c0b4b8wcxeRmTo5cAKNQ0K0%2BDvOhLRh%2Bp4TwNtta26qgJAeQO3xnXAvobW4WAr0EkXoZmXCnYRUzPJ3UFtDGJc%3D69ef2bb637cd8a17710e28acb9872e7e9b0f0c04;\r\nContent-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded\r\n\r\nlogin_token=5459e2c58d673&password=*******5&email=*********%40beatswitch.com&submission='
```

These two headers are almost alike, except for '\r\n' tags. Can someone tell me if these two headers are indeed the same? I can't understand why one of them is working while the other is not.

Comment: I see a lot of cookies and headers you propably wouldn't need. Try it out in a webclient http://www.hurl.it/. If it works there, it should work evrywhere. Get rid of all headers/cookies you don't need. (Hint the utm-cookies are from google. You don't need them https://support.google.com/urchin/answer/28710?hl=en)

Comment: @VincentBeltman Thanks for helping
(1) I don't know which parameters 'requests' appends automatically that's why I attached everything myself to make python's request similar to Chrome's.
(2) Hurl.it doesn't work. I added the required parameters and various combinations of cookies but still no results.

Comment: If you say chrome. Do you mean the browser or the web-client-extension?

Comment: I mean chrome browser. Using chrome developer tools I found out the html request generated by the 'login' button. I am trying to regenerate that request using Python and requests.

Comment: Try to do the same in the chrome developers tool. If it works there, it is propably a forgotten cookie or a wrong session id in my experience. The developers tool sends more headers and cookies than it should.

Comment: @VincentBeltman I have been trying for hours to find that 'forgotten cookie'. lol

Comment: When I deleted this cookie: bravoure_property_md_2_8_3__2_2_0 I couldn't log in anymore.

Comment: @VincentBeltman Have a look at the edited post please.

Comment: What happens if you use the same session id as the browser? And what response are you getting? 400? 200? Error message?

Comment: When there is anything wrong with the request the website redirects to the login page with an error saying 'Please enter correct credentials'... The id that works in browser doesn't work in python for some reason.. The response still is 200 but the body of the page contains this error text

Comment: I've no clue. My last guess would be a missing request. Or still a missing cookie.